# Show multiple values of a many-to-many query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three table:

1. user
2. products
3. user selected products

A user can select multiple products.

I want to write an SQL query to find all users, and also list all of the products they have selected.

This is my query so far:

```
 SELECT
    u.user_id,CONCAT(u.firstName,' ',u.lastName)as name, u.email,
    (SELECT
        p.product_id
    FROM  
        user_selected_products p
    WHERE
        p.user_id= u.user_id
    )as productsSelected

FROM 
users u;
```

And here are my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE users(
   user_id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
   firstName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
   lastName VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
   email VARCHAR (80) NOT NULL   
);       

CREATE TABLE products (
   product_id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
   product_name VARCHAR(150) NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (product_id),
   INDEX productName( product_name )
); 

CREATE TABLE user_selected_products (
   user_id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL , 
   product_id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL , 
   INDEX selectedProductName(user_id,product_id )
);
```

I am getting the following error:

> : Subquery returns more than 1 row

the subquery is not working because I am trying to return multiple values. What is the proper way to write this query?

**UPDATE**

I want to see all the products that a user has selected

the table `user_selected_products` will have multiple results in it. i.e a user might select multiple products. The query therefore needs to return all the results for the multiple products that a user might select.

Comment: Do you want to see all products or only one?

Comment: What are your desired results?  You're error is coming from the correlated subquery -- remove that and just use a join (possibly outer).  Depending on your results, you may want to use `group_concat` to combine to the same row.

Comment: i want to see all the products that a user has selected

Comment: does it have to be in a single row? in a single field?                                     As I understand it you want 1 row = name,email,(list of products) so 1 row with 3 fields and last fields is an array of item id's

Comment: Can you post some sample data with your expected results?

Comment: I think this guide might answer your question http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2914/rolling-up-multiple-rows-into-a-single-row-and-column-for-sql-server-data/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the problem; The reason you are getting this error is pretty self explanatory, you have a subquery that returns multiple values, but are trying to put it as one cell of your result table, which is not allowed. Cells cannot have more than one value.

The solution does not require a subquery. Your user_selected_products table has everything you need. If you want to see user and product information along side of that, you can just use joins, like this:

```
SELECT u.user_id, CONCAT(u.firstName, ' ', u.lastName) AS name, u.email, p.product_id
FROM users u
JOIN user_selected_products p
ON p.user_id = u.user_id
```

This will return multiple rows for each user/product combination. If you would like to see all product_ids in the same cell, you can use the `GROUP_CONCAT()` function which will separate them by commas. You just need to them group by user_id, like this:

```
SELECT u.user_id, CONCAT(u.firstName, ' ', u.lastName) AS name, u.email,
   GROUP_CONCAT(p.product_id) AS selectedProducts
FROM users u
JOIN user_selected_products p ON p.user_id = u.user_id
GROUP BY u.user_id;
```

**EDIT**

Here is a shortened [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/587a2/1) example that demonstrates how `GROUP_CONCAT` works. If this is not how you want the data displayed, there are ways to change the delimiter for concatenated items and you can design it how you want.

Also, if you want to see a row for each user, regardless of whether or not they have any selected products, you can do an `OUTER JOIN` to the users table.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need subquery, you can use `left join` as below

```
SELECT
  u.user_id,CONCAT(u.firstName,' ',u.lastName)as name, u.email,
  p.product_id as productsSelected                        
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN user_selected_products p on p.user_id= u.user_id;
```

if you want to see all praodutcs in one row try to use [group_concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
SELECT
u.user_id,CONCAT(u.firstName,' ',u.lastName)as name, u.email,
group_concat(p.product_id) as productsSelected                        
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN user_selected_products p on p.user_id= u.user_id
GROUP BY u.user_id;
```

Comment: but the user_selected_products should be returning multiple results . With your code its is only returning 1 result

Comment: @PaulKendal Do you want to see all products in one row?

Comment: @PaulKendal I added one more soluition

Comment: Good catch using `left join` to get a row for all users, even if they don't have any selected products. I completely overlooked that.